# Hiding all series except one very slow in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, highcharts

I have a highchart that contains 8 series, each having 60 data points. I have captured the event when a user clicks on a series in the legend, so when a user clicks on a series all other series are hidden in the graph.

This is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i ++) {
    if (chart.series[i] == selectedSerie) {
        chart.series[i].show ();
    } else {
        chart.series[i].hide ();
    }
}
```

This works just fine, except in Internet Explorer where it takes a very long time to hide all and show just one series. I guess this is due to a redraw of the chart when a series is being shown or hidden. Does anyone know a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you put up a jsFiddle with some sample data?

Comment: Sure! http://jsfiddle.net/dRt89/2/

Comment: It is slow in FF 13 as well. I turned off the shadows on the series and still slow.

Comment: I am now using a setTimeout to show and hide the pens one by one. This works ok as long as the dataset of a series is not too large, otherwise I will still get the terminate script popup.